# ISDT Q8 cells do not charge evenly

Tags: battery-cell

[image]my ISTD Q8 charger cannot charge my 6s 5500 mah battery equally. I calibrated, but it still didn't improve, then I tried self-testing. When you go to the balance section, it gives an error with the code 407. Can you help me to solve this problem?